# Kruskal's Algorithm: Update MST when an edge becomes mandatory

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-algorithm, kruskals-algorithm

It is given an undirected graph G = (V, E). First it is asked what is the cost of MST.
I can easily find out using Kruskall algorithm, like this:

```
G = (V, E)
for each edge (u, v) in E sorted by wight
{
    if(Find(u) != Find(v))
    {
        Add (u, v) to the MST
        Union(u, v); // put u and v in the same set
    }
}
```

After that, for each edge in the initial graph, it is asked what will the cost of new MST it that edge shall be present in the Minimum Spanning Tree.

If an edge is already present in the MST, the answer remains the same. Otherwise, I can run Kruskall once again. The pseudocode is the following:

```
G = (V, E)
G1 = runKruskall(G)

for each edge (u, v) in E
{
    ClearUnionSets()
    if (u, v) in G1
    {
        print costOf(G1)
    } else {
        Union(u, v)
        G2 = runKruskall(G)
        print costOf(G2)
    }
}
```

The problem with that approach is that the total complexity would be: O(E*E)

My question is if there exist a better solution for updating MST as described above.

What I was thinking is that when running for the first time Kruskall, for every edge (u, v), were u and v are in the same set, find the the maximum weighted edge already present in the partial MST that makes a cycle with (u, v) and store that information in a matrix M at M[u][v]. Doing this, the problem of updating MST when a edge becomes mandatory would be solved in O(1).

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every edge u-v that is not on the MST, the smallest spanning tree including the edge is the one where u-v replaces the largest edge on the path from u to v on the MST.

The edge to be replaced can be found efficiently as follows. First, root the MST at an arbitrary vertex. We will modify the algorithm to find the [lowest common ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) (LCA) of two vertices, described [here](https://www.quora.com/Algorithms-What-are-the-specifics-in-implementing-an-O-N-log-N-Lowest-Common-Ancestor-algorithm/answer/Raziman-T-V). In addition to storing the 2^i th parent for each vertex, we will also store the largest edge on the path to the 2^i th parent. Using this array, while we calculate the LCA we will also calculate the largest edge on the path to the LCA, which gives us the largest edge on the path between the two vertices.

Preprocessing involves finding the MST in O(E log E) and building the parent table for LCA in O(N log N), with the requirement of O(N log N) space. After this, finding the modified MST for each edge requires only the evaluation of LCA once, which can be performed in O(log N). Thus the total complexity is only O(E log E).